# Can Zynq-7000 be singled steped

Tags: linux, debugging, arm, xilinx, zynq

I want to use linux for the ARM core of Zynq-7000.  But have a quesion on:
Can I single step debug the kernel from the IDE instead of just printk?  Does the hard ARM core allows single step into the kernel and expose all the registers, flags, pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclipse-based tools for PowerPC and Microblaze (the [Xilinx SDK](http://www.xilinx.com/tools/sdk.htm)) can do single step, and also supports the Zynq-7000.

From the linked Xilinx webpage:

> SDK includes an integrated debugger supporting Zynq-7000 EPP, MicroBlaze™, and PowerPC processors. You can set breakpoints or watchpoints, step through program execution, view the program variables and stack, and view the contents of the memory in the system. You can also simultaneously debug programs running on different processors (in a multi-processor system), all from within the same debug environment.

Comment: Thanks.  Saw that but wasn't sure before that ARM single step is similar to x86, with break point supported by CPU.  Just want to make sure there is no difference to single step a kernel, and to single step an application.